# Apply master page for all subsites in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Working on a SP2010 Standard  intranet/extranet project.I have created a master page to use for all sites.
But i would like to apply the masterpages to all sites and subsites.
So what i'm trying to achieve is when i create a new site i want it t use this master page as default.
Any ideas?
Is this possible without enabling the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Non Publishing Sites]**

Check link below if you want to set master page for one web or for all webs in a site collection.

http://blog.incworx.com/blog/sharepoint-2010-tips-and-tricks/how-to-change-the-master-page-of-a-sharepoint-2010-team-site

If you want to set the master page automatically when a new web is created (and master page is just for your particular site collection) Host WebProvisioned event at site collection level and set the master page when WebProvisioned event is fired. Check link below for help:

http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2010/10/07/how-to-attach-an-event-receiver-to-the-web-added-event-and-for-what-purpose/

You might also want to check [WebProvisioned event receiver – a practical example](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2010/09/webprovisioned-event-receiver-practical.html)

Comment: Thanks Ashish i did follow this artcile:
http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/03/26/deploying-a-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

But when i deploy my solution and activate the feature on a site collection and then create a subsite of that site collection the master page doesn't show up.

Comment: Thanks for the links
Thanks Ashish i did follow this artcile:
http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/03/26/deploying-a-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

But when i deploy my solution and activate the feature on a site collection and then create a subsite of that site collection the master page doesn't show up.

Do i need to activate the publishing infrastrcuture feature for this to work?

The powershell script link you forwarded should do the job but i would prefer a feature for this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks Ashish.
The link you posted above using the powershell make alot of sense as the team site doesn't have the links to change masterpage under look and feel.

Comment: That's true, I dont like to enable Publishing Features just to have those extra things that comes with it if I am not going to use Publishing Features.